# Hw can i send a search query to thesuarus.com through html page?

Tags: java, html

I have made a html page which has a text field and a submit button ,the user enters a word in the text field and clicks submit . There is a servlet which fetches the users input through request.getParameter(). Now i want to send this input word to thesaurus.com and retrieve the synonym for the word and send this synonym back to user as response i want to include this functionality in the above said servlet itself....plz help!

Comment: Had you looked, you would have seen that thesaurus.com has an API you can use:  http://developer.dictionary.com/

Comment: ya i know it but can u plz tel how to use the api.....it wud b a grt help

Answer (score 0):

you can use java.net api or alternatively use can apache HTTP client .using java.net api just create url object and open connection and send parameter using write method and get the response.

To check what parameter is sent you can use http live header plugin of mozila

Comment: thanx but can b more specific i mean if u can plz post some code snippets that wud b rilly helpful!!